# What is difference between Test case and Test case(if we are not taking automation into consideration(

Tags: manual-testing

If Automation is excluded and from manual testing point of view, what is diffrerence between Test Strategy, Test Scenario, Test case and Test Script

Comment: what is the difference of asking in SO or using a search engine...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**

**Test Strategy**

A Test Strategy document is a high level document and normally developed by project manager. This document defines “Software Testing Approach” to achieve testing objectives. The Test Strategy is normally derived from the Business Requirement Specification document.

Some companies include the “Test Approach” or “Strategy” inside the Test Plan, which is fine and it is usually the case for small projects. However, for larger projects, there is one Test Strategy document and different number of Test Plans for each phase or level of testing.

Components of the Test Strategy document

1)Scope and Objectives

2)Business issues

3)Roles and responsibilities

4)Communication and status reporting

5)Test deliverability

6)Industry standards to follow

7)Test automation and tools

8)Testing measurements and metrices

9)Risks and mitigation

10)Defect reporting and tracking

11)Change and configuration management

12)Training plan

**

**Test Scenario**

A scenario is a story that describes a hypothetical situation. In testing, you check how the program copes with this hypothetical situation.
The ideal scenario test is credible, motivating, easy to evaluate, and complex.
Scenarios are usually different from test cases in that test cases are single steps and scenarios cover a number of steps. Test suites and scenarios can be used in concert for complete system tests.
A Scenario is any functionality that can be tested. It is also called Test Condition ,or Test Possibility.

**

**Test Cases**

In software engineering, a test case is a set of conditions or variables under which a tester will determine if a requirement upon an application is partially or fully satisfied. It may take many test cases to determine that a requirement is fully satisfied. In order to fully test that all the requirements of an application are met, there must be at least one test case for each requirement unless a requirement has sub requirements. In that situation, each sub requirement must have at least one test case .

A test case is also defined as a sequence of steps to test the correct behavior of a functionality/feature of an application.
A sequence of steps consisting of actions to be performed on the system under test. (These steps are sometimes called the test procedure or test script). These actions are often associated with some set of data (preloaded or input during the test). The combination of actions taken and data provided to the system under test leads to the test condition. This condition tends to produce results that the test can compare with the expected results; I.e assess quality under the given test condition. The actions can be performed serially, in parallel, or in some other combination of consecution.

**

**Test Script**

Test Script is a set of instructions (written using a scripting/programming language) that is performed on a system under test to verify that the system performs as expected. Test scripts are used in automated testing.

Sometimes, a set of instructions (written in a human language), used in manual testing,  is also called a Test Script but a better term for that would be a Test Case.

Comment: I would like to enter an example for test scenario and test case.
Test Scenario:
To test the login functionality.

Test Case:

Steps:
1) Enter Username.
2) Enter Password.
3) Click on Login button.

Answer (score 0):

Test Scenario means " What to be tested" and test case means " How to be tested".

Test case: It consist of test case name, Precondition, steps / input condition, expected result.

Test Scenario: Test scenario consists of a detailed test procedure. We can also say that a test scenario has many test cases associated with it. Before executing the test scenario we need to think of test cases for each scenario.

Test Script: A Test Script is a set of instructions (written using a programming language) that is performed on a system under test to verify that the system performs as expected.

Test scripts is the term used when referring to automated testing. When you're creating a test script, you are using an automation tool to create your script.

Answer (score 0):

## Test strategy

outlines the testing approach and everything else that surrounds it. It is different from the test plan, in the sense that a Test strategy is only a sub set of the test plan. It is a hard core test document that is to an extent generic and static. There is also an argument about at what levels test strategy or plan is used- but I really do not see any discerning difference.

Example: Test plan gives the information of who is going to test at what time. For example: Module 1 is going to be tested by “X tester”. If tester Y replaces X for some reason, the test plan has to be updated.

On the contrary, test strategy is going to have details like – “Individual modules are to be tested by test team members. “ In this case, it does not matter who is testing it- so it’s generic and the change in the team member does not have to be updated, keeping it static.

## Test scenario

This is a one line pointer that testers create as an initial, transitional step into the test design phase. This is mostly a one line definition of “What” we are going to test with respect to a certain feature. Usually, test scenarios are an input for the creation of test cases. In agile projects, Test scenarios are the only test design outputs and no test cases are written following these. A test scenario might result in multiple tests.

Examples test scenarios:

1. Validate if a new country can be added by the Admin
2. Validate if an existing country can be deleted by the admin
3. Validate if an existing country can be updated

## Test Case:

Test Case is a commonly used term for a specific test. This is usually the smallest unit of testing. A Test Case will consist of information such as requirements testing, test steps, verification steps, prerequisites, outputs, test environment, etc.
A set of inputs, execution preconditions, and expected outcomes developed for a particular objective, such as to exercise a particular program path or to verify compliance with a specific requirement.

## Test Script:

Commonly used to refer to the instructions for a particular test that will be carried out by an automated test tool

Answer (score 0):

**Test Scenarios:** A high-level/simple/individual test panorama of actual system capability. We no need to define a clear step-by-step way of validation at this stage as we define test scenarios at very early stages of software life cycle. This will not be considered for test plan as this is a non-defined item in terms resource allocation.

**Test Case:** Is a document which consists of system specific prerequisites, but no step-by-step validation. In test case traceability we use a test case document against requirements. This is how we will define the test coverage matrix against requirements. In most of the cases, a test case will cover multiple test scenarios. A test case will carry complexity. Test cases are used for calculation of testing efforts for a particular release with respect to code version.

**Test Script(without Automation/programming language context):**  Every one aware of the fact that a test script is an automation program which is uniquely mapped to a test case. But without automation as well we can use this term especially when you are using Rational Quality Manager(RQM) as your test repo.
1.When a test case has multiple versions and the testing team needs to maintain all test case versions against multiple system code versions.In this case, one test case will have multiple test scripts(one for each version). 
2.When a test case produces different results in different environments(Operating system or technology.. etc), a test case will be mapped to multiple test scripts which have the expected results change but entire test case remains same.

In either of the above cases, while creating test plan we need to first decide on which version of the test case(in other terms, test script) for execution based on code version or the environment.

Hope this helps to answer your question.